# JavaScript: print the ticketPrice and set the ticketPrice variable

Tags: javascript

```
var ticketType;
ticketType = prompt("What sort of tickets would you like");
document.write("Ticket Type Cost is: " + ticketType);
document.write("<br/>");

if (ticketType == "A") {
document.write("$100");
}   
else if (ticketType == "a") {
document.write("$100"); 
}
else if (ticketType == "B") {
document.write("$75"); 
}
else if (ticketType == "b") {
document.write("$75"); 
}
else if (ticketType == "C") {
document.write("$50");
}
else if (ticketType == "c") {
document.write("$50");
}
else {
document.write("Invalid ticket type");
}

var ticketQty;
ticketQty = prompt("How many tickeets would you like");
var ticketQty = parseInt(ticketQty);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("Ticket Qty is: " + ticketQty);
document.write("<br/>");
if (ticketQty < 0 || ticketQty > 100) {
document.write("Invalid Qty"); 
}

var ticketPrice = ;
if (ticketPrice > 0 && ticketQty > 0 && ticketQty < 100) {
document.write("Ticket payment required is:$" + (ticketPrice*ticketQty));
}
```

I need help with this last variable 'ticketPrice'. I have tried a lot of different things but none of them seem to work. What should I set my ticketPrice variable to and do i need to add anything else to my code or remove anything in order to make it work properly.

Comment: `var ticketPrice = ;` --> Syntax error. Your code can't run. Open your console (F12), it's telling you that.

Comment: @evantenken, it looks like you liked the answer from simonlegg the best, so you should "accept" that answer, and probably upvote him as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to set the `ticketPrice` variable inside your `if` statements when you know the price. So you should define the `var ticketPrice` at the top and in each if statement where you are doing `document.write` also assign the variable.

```
var ticketType;
var ticketPrice;
ticketType = prompt("What sort of tickets would you like");
document.write("Ticket Type Cost is: " + ticketType);
document.write("<br/>");

if (ticketType == "A") {
  document.write("$100");
  ticketPrice = 100;
}   
else if (ticketType == "a") {
  document.write("$100"); 
  ticketPrice = 100;
}
else if (ticketType == "B") {
  document.write("$75"); 
  ticketPrice = 75;
}
else if (ticketType == "b") {
  document.write("$75");
  ticketPrice = 75;
}
else if (ticketType == "C") {
  document.write("$50");
  ticketPrice = 50;
}
else if (ticketType == "c") {
  document.write("$50");
  ticketPrice = 50;
}
else {
  document.write("Invalid ticket type");
}

var ticketQty;
ticketQty = prompt("How many tickeets would you like");
var ticketQty = parseInt(ticketQty);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("Ticket Qty is: " + ticketQty);
document.write("<br/>");
if (ticketQty < 0 || ticketQty > 100) {
  document.write("Invalid Qty"); 
}

if (ticketPrice > 0 && ticketQty > 0 && ticketQty < 100) {
  document.write("Ticket payment required is:$"
   + (ticketPrice*ticketQty));
}
```

You should also consider refactoring this to reduce some of the duplication around your `if` statements

```
if (ticketType == "A") {
  document.write("$100");
  ticketPrice = 100;
}   
else if (ticketType == "a") {
  document.write("$100"); 
  ticketPrice = 100;
}
else if (ticketType == "B") {
  document.write("$75"); 
  ticketPrice = 75;
}
else if (ticketType == "b") {
  document.write("$75");
  ticketPrice = 75;
}
else if (ticketType == "C") {
  document.write("$50");
  ticketPrice = 50;
}
else if (ticketType == "c") {
  document.write("$50");
  ticketPrice = 50;
}
else {
  document.write("Invalid ticket type");
}
```

Could become

```
if (ticketType.toLowerCase() === "a") {
  document.write("$100");
  ticketPrice = 100;
} else if (ticketType.toLowerCase() === "b") {
  document.write("$75");
  ticketPrice = 75;
} else if (ticketType.toLowerCase() === "c") {
  document.write("$50");
  ticketPrice = 50;
} else {
  document.write("Invalid ticket type");
}
```

Reducing duplication here would make it slightly easier to update the prices of your tickets for example as you wouldn't need to change it in 2 places (the uppercase and lowercase blocks)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @evantenken if this answer solved your question it'd be great if you could accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Change `ticketPrice = ;` to `ticketPrice;` as it produce error.

```js
var ticketType;
ticketType = prompt("What sort of tickets would you like");
document.write("Ticket Type Cost is: " + ticketType);
document.write("<br/>");

if (ticketType == "A") {
document.write("$100");
}   
else if (ticketType == "a") {
document.write("$100"); 
}
else if (ticketType == "B") {
document.write("$75"); 
}
else if (ticketType == "b") {
document.write("$75"); 
}
else if (ticketType == "C") {
document.write("$50");
}
else if (ticketType == "c") {
document.write("$50");
}
else {
document.write("Invalid ticket type");
}

var ticketQty;
ticketQty = prompt("How many tickeets would you like");
var ticketQty = parseInt(ticketQty);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("Ticket Qty is: " + ticketQty);
document.write("<br/>");
if (ticketQty < 0 || ticketQty > 100) {
document.write("Invalid Qty"); 
}

var ticketPrice;
if (ticketPrice > 0 && ticketQty > 0 && ticketQty < 100) {
document.write("Ticket payment required is:$" + (ticketPrice*ticketQty));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value for ticketPrice in your set of `if` statements, and declare it ahead of time.

```
var ticketType;
var ticketPrice;
ticketType = prompt("What sort of tickets would you like");
document.write("Ticket Type Cost is: " + ticketType);
document.write("<br/>");

if (ticketType == "A") {
    ticketPrice=100;
}   
else if (ticketType == "a") {
    ticketPrice=100; 
}
else if (ticketType == "B") {
    ticketPrice=75; 
}
else if (ticketType == "b") {
    ticketPrice=$75; 
}
else if (ticketType == "C") {
    ticketPrice=50;
}
else if (ticketType == "c") {
    ticketPrice=50;
}
else {
    document.write("Invalid ticket type");
}

if (typeof ticketPrice !== "undefined" && ticketPrice !== null) 
{
    document.write("$");
    document.write(ticketPrice);
}
var ticketQty;
ticketQty = prompt("How many tickeets would you like");
var ticketQty = parseInt(ticketQty);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("Ticket Qty is: " + ticketQty);
document.write("<br/>");
if (ticketQty < 0 || ticketQty > 100) {
    document.write("Invalid Qty"); 
}

var ticketPrice = ;
if (ticketPrice > 0 && ticketQty > 0 && ticketQty < 100) {
    document.write("Ticket payment required is:$" + (ticketPrice*ticketQty));
}
```

Comment: Additionally, when you are checking for both "A" and "a", you have a `toUpperCase` [method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp) for converting a value to uppercase. `toUpperCase(ticketType)=="A"` will check for both "A" and "a". But that wasn't your question

Comment: You would need to have a check for `ticketPrice` where you are writing to the document, otherwise if `ticketType` was undefined you'd end up with
`Invalid ticket type`
`$undefined`

Comment: Modified the answer. Thanks @SimonLegg